# how to move page sections (paragraphs) on web page using mouse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, resume

I have a `resume` displayed on a `web page`. which contains `sections (paragraphs)` like `education`, `experience`, `projects` etc, here `client` wants to move these `sections` on the page by `dragging` mouse on the `paragraphs(sections)` of `web page`. how can i implement this feature. I am using `ruby on rails` framework. is there any `rails` gem or `jquery` framework for achieving this task?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, jQuery UI Sortable, try it: https://jqueryui.com/sortable/

If you have something like this:

```
<div id="sections">
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
  <p>...</p>
</div>
```

Then all you need to do is to install Sortable and:

```
$( "#sections" ).sortable();
```

You can find full API documentation here: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/

And here's jQuery UI for rails: https://github.com/jquery-ui-rails/jquery-ui-rails

Comment: Thanks, vasily. on the same web page i have two options like "download as pdf" and "download as word" options. will these changes reflect in this also?

Comment: No problem! If they're children of `<div id="sections">`, then yes. But there're helpful `handle` (http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-handle) and `cancel` (http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-cancel) options, read more about them, they're what you need.